# Texture Baking With Dark Patches

Tags: texture-baking

I am making a link model following a tutorial on youtube. I tried to bake a texture that has ambient occlusion. Every other part of the model works fine, but for some reason the back of the shield has these dark patches even though there is nothing obscuring it. I noticed the dark patches align with the faces of the model and have already tried merging by distance and checking the normals.[image]

Comment: what is a link model?

Comment: Link model as in a model of Link the game character